# Same internal IP on Azure Ubuntu VM's

Tags: azure

I span up a Ubuntu 16.04 Classic VM and another Ubuntu 16.04 Resource VM and both of them has the same internal ip. How is that possible? What should I do to get a different internal ip?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Does two VMs in the same vnet?

Comment: I chose the default installation for the VM's didn't configure vnet by myself. How to check the vnet?

Comment: @Minisha if two VMs in the same Vnet, VMs will not get the same internal IP address. You can find the vnet in your resource group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created both of the VMs in a different Vnet. so they are in different virtual networks. you need to create them in the same network that way they will get different IPs and will be able to talk to each other.

Comment: could you refer to the documentation I could follow to create 2 VMS in same Vnet for them to talk with each other and to have 2 ips?

Comment: well, it depends how do you want to create those. if you are using portal just select the same vnet\subnet when creating the second vm